# Target not instantiable while building MailThiefFiveFourCompatible (Laravel 5.1 to 5.4)

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.4

I'm in the process of upgrading our Laravel 5.1 app to Laravel 5.5, and have been following the upgrade guides.

Whilst performing the upgrade from 5.3 to 5.4, I've run into an issue with failing unit tests that use MailThief's `InteractsWithMail` trait.

composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*",
    "jeremykendall/php-domain-parser": "^3.0",
    "laracasts/flash": "^2.0",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.21",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1",
    "league/oauth2-client": "1.4.*",
    "microsoft/microsoft-graph": "^0.1.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
    "dusterio/laravel-aws-worker": "^0.1.9",
    "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev",
    "anchu/ftp": "^2.0",
    "predis/predis": "~1.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "laravel/homestead": "^4.0",
    "tightenco/mailthief": ">=0.3.8",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.1",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~3.1",
    "laravel/browser-kit-testing": "^2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/Support/Helpers.php"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
      "php artisan ide-helper:generate -M",
      "php artisan ide-helper:meta",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  }
}
```

Unit test stack trace:

```
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory] is not instantiable while building [MailThief\MailThiefFiveFourCompatible].
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:895
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:735
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:608
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:575
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:728
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:862
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:790
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:756
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:608
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:575
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:728
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1172
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:159
 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:128
 /app/vendor/tightenco/mailthief/src/Testing/InteractsWithMail.php:21
 /app/vendor/tightenco/mailthief/src/Testing/InteractsWithMail.php:59
```

I'm using Homestead hosted on Windows 10.